# How do I deal with this strange inductor?

Tags: inductor, parallel, inductance, series

I'm trying to solve for the equivalent inductance between terminals a and b but there's this 2 Henry inductor on the top right that doesn't fit with the basic rules of series and parallel connections. How do I deal with it? Do I just ignore it?

[image]

Comment: If you injected some voltage between points a and b, would current flow through that inductor? Think about it. As a general rule, you should show some progress here, not just ask for general homework advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That 2 H inductor is in series with an infinite impedance, an open circuit. Therefore its effect on the circuit is just like using an open circuit instead of the inductor, the same as ignoring it, or removing it.